# NodeJS Application cannot access remote REST APIs

Tags: node.js, proxy

I have an application running on NodeJS locally and it "communicates" with three different APIs. Problem is the company I'm on has a proxy and I keep getting

```
 { [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

My proxy environment variables are set correctly (also NPM proxy/https-proxy), is there anything else I should consider? I know this is a wide problem, but this happens all the time on my Application while the other programs with external connections work.

Comment: When does this happen: when running your Node application or while doing the npm install? What package are you using to do the REST calls?

Comment: It's while my application tries doing REST Calls I get these. I'm using StrongLoop.